# jQuery 2.x issue on addEventListener while using Microsoft Web Browser OCX control

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, emulation, ocx, ieframe.dll

I am using IE OCX on Progress ABL container and has forced the emulation of IE10 by adding a new DWORD entry on windows registry(on FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION). The web file I want to open on this embedded browser includes jQuery version 2.2.4 and I am getting the script error:

> Line: 3573 [document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed );],
>   Char: 4,
>   Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
>   Code: 0,
>   URL: filepath/jquery-2.2.4.js.

The same error persists even if i force the emulation of IE11 and use jQuery 2.x. But no error if I use jQuery 1.12.4. Emulated version is correct. Is that the issue of Microsoft web browser ocx? I have IE11 on my machine.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION does change the userAgent. But i found the doctype specification on my old webpages like this:
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` was compelling the browser to render the page in quirks mode and hence the error on jquery was occured. So i found 3 ways to resolve this issue (to ensure the standard mode):

1. Using `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
2. Using '`<!DOCTYPE html>`' and following html5 standards for new webpages
3. Specifying the metatag:`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">`

This is also quite helpful: [doctype overview](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/the-doctype-tag-and-its-effect-on-page-rendering.html#fbid=uIhobX9PCaN)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the 1.x branch of jQuery, as the 2.x branch removed a lot of legacy code which was required for compatibility with older browsers and IE (which is what the OCX control will be using)